# How to identify schedulable nodes in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to (programatically) get a list of all schedulable nodes in my kubernetes cluster.

I'm fairly sure this used to be possible by looking at `.spec.unschedulable` in the full output of `kubectl get nodes` (using JSON or template output), but now it seems this info is inside the  `scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/taints` key, which is much harder to parse and just doesn't feel like the right place.

Is there some other way to find this info? Am I missing something obvious? I'm using version 1.5.1 currently.

UPDATE: I can *almost* get there with some Go templating:

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{with $x := index .metadata.annotations "scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/taints"}}{{.}}{{end}}{{end}}'
[{"key":"dedicated","value":"master","effect":"NoSchedule"}]
```

But that leaves me with a blob of JSON that I can't parse in the template, and I still have to invert the results and get the node name out.

UPDATE 2: Apparently unschedulable nodes should have `.spec.unschedulable` set. This doesn't seem to always be the case; not sure if it's due to a bug or a misunderstanding on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working go text/template that works now that `spec.taints` is GA:

```
{{/* scehdulable.gotmpl */}}
{{- range .items }}
  {{- $taints:="" }}
  {{- range .spec.taints }}
    {{- if eq .effect "NoSchedule" }}
      {{- $taints = print $taints .key "," }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- if not $taints }}
    {{- .metadata.name}}{{ "\n" }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

```sh
kubectl get no -o go-template-file=./schedulable.gotmpl
kind-worker
kind-worker2
```

Compact version:

```sh
kubectl get no -o 'go-template={{range .items}}{{$taints:=""}}{{range .spec.taints}}{{if eq .effect "NoSchedule"}}{{$taints = print $taints .key ","}}{{end}}{{end}}{{if not $taints}}{{.metadata.name}}{{ "\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}'
```

Comment: If you don't care about the names of the taints, try: 
`go-template={{range .items}}{{$sched:=true}}{{range .spec.taints}}{{if eq .effect "NoSchedule"}}{{$sched = false}}{{end}}{{end}}{{if $sched}}{{.metadata.name}}{{ "\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}`

Answer (score 3):

Though quite late to the party, I needed something of the similar today to determine when the scheduling of pods would actually start succeeding:

```
kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name} {.spec.taints[?(@.effect=='NoSchedule')].effect}{\"\n\"}{end}" | awk 'NF==1 {print $0}'
```

<s>this is essentially just a more compact template than the one the OP posted with the inversion done by filterung with `awk`.</s>

*Edit:* after trying to use the command I had posted earlier, I realized that it would only work in the edge case of a single master. Thus I have extended the command to first print all node names along with `NoSchedule` taints (if present) and afterwards removing all lines with more than one column using `awk` (This is what `NF==1` does).

Answer (score 1):

`unschedulable` defaults to false, so the value will not appear in the spec unless it is set to `true`. The value is implicit in the spec.

Comment: I am aware of this. As per my update, I had an unschedulable node without `.spec.unschedulable` being set. The node did have a "taint" to say it was unschedulable and no pods could be scheduled onto the node. Currently, I suspect it was simply a bug.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for an answer on newer versions of Kubernetes, the following will allow you to retrieve unschedulable nodes:

```
kubectl get nodes --field-selector spec.unschedulable=true
```

while the following will allow you to retrieve schedulable nodes:

```
kubectl get nodes --field-selector spec.unschedulable=false
```